# Conditional Query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am into creating a conditional search which will depend upon say about 9 parameters. For now I am only using 4 and it has become quite large and hectic to maintain. Can someone suggest the best way so that I can shorten my line of codes and maintain it easily. Below is my code

```
if($min_year=="Select" && $max_year=="") {
        if($makes=='All' && $models=='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID 
                    and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID 
                    and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");                                   
        } elseif($makes!='All' && $models=='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails,vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and 
                    vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID  LIMIT $start, $per_page
                    ");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and 
                    vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");           

        } elseif($makes=='All' && $models!='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails,vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID 
                     LIMIT $start, $per_page"); 
            $select_count =  mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");

        } elseif($makes!='All' && $models!='All Models' && $makes!='select' && $models!='select') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where models.modelID=$models and models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID
                     and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where models.modelID=$models and models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID
                     and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");          
        } else {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, 
                    manufacturers, vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and 
                    models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, vehicles 
                        where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");                 
        }
    } elseif($min_year!="Select" && $max_year==""){
        if($makes=='All' && $models=='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and vehicles.year>=$min_year and
                    vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page 
                    ");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and vehicles.year>=$min_year and
                    vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");       

        } elseif($makes!='All' && $models=='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and 
                    vehicles.year>=$min_year and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID 
                     LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count =  mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and 
                    vehicles.year>=$min_year and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID 
                    ");         

        } elseif($makes=='All' && $models!='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and vehicles.year>=$min_year and
                     models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and vehicles.year>=$min_year and
                     models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");              
        } else {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails,vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where models.modelID=$models and models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID
                     and vehicles.year>=$min_year and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count =  mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where models.modelID=$models and models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID
                     and vehicles.year>=$min_year and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");         
        }       
    } elseif($min_year=="Select" && $max_year!=""){
        if($makes=='All' && $models=='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and vehicles.year<=$max_year and
                    vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID  LIMIT $start, $per_page
                    ");
            $select_count =  mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and vehicles.year<=$max_year and
                    vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");       

        } elseif($makes!='All' && $models=='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and 
                    vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID 
                     LIMIT $start, $per_page"); 
            $select_count =  mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and 
                    vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID 
                    ");      

        } elseif($makes=='All' && $models!='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and vehicles.year<=$max_year and
                     models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count =  mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and vehicles.year<=$max_year and
                     models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");              
        } else {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where models.modelID=$models and models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID
                     and vehicles.year<=$max_year and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page");
           $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where models.modelID=$models and models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID
                     and vehicles.year<=$max_year and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");             
        }       
    } else {
        if($makes=='All' && $models=='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.year>=$min_year
                     and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page 
                    ");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.year>=$min_year
                     and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");      

        } elseif($makes!='All' && $models=='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and 
                    vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.year>=$min_year and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID 
                    and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page ");  
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where  models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID and 
                    vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.year>=$min_year and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID 
                    and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");       

        } elseif($makes=='All' && $models!='All Models') {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.year>=$min_year and
                     models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where vehicles.modelID=models.modelID and vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.year>=$min_year and
                     models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID");              
        } else {
            $select = mysql_query("select models.modelID, models.manufacturerID, models.modelName, manufacturers.manufacturerID, 
                    manufacturers.manufacturerName, manufacturers.manufacturerDetails, vehicles.* from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where models.modelID=$models and models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID
                     and vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.year>=$min_year and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID 
                      LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $select_count = mysql_query("select count(vehicles.modelID) as count from models, manufacturers, 
                    vehicles where models.modelID=$models and models.manufacturerID=$makes and vehicles.modelID=models.modelID
                     and vehicles.year<=$max_year and vehicles.year>=$min_year and models.manufacturerID=manufacturers.manufacturerID 
                     ");            
        }       
    }
```

As you can see these loops are getting longer and complex . Please suggest something. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into using prepared statements?

Comment: Store the parameters in variables based on the conditions. Place the variable in a single query outside the condition. Otherwise, try to study conditional statements in mysql query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: @AshwinMukhija : No I have not. Let me see that.

Comment: you can set the `$select_count` variable with query string. and after all checking run the `mysql_query($select_count);` one time.

Comment: Wow that's an Array of queries!

Comment: @ Mithun Sen this will not remove the complex nested structure and will do nothing towards maintainability or readability

Comment: @Hanky Panky ㇱ : Yeah thats a lot. And thats just the beginning

Comment: @Pankrates: Yes, you said that correct. So what are options now?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: You could give PL/SQL a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your sql more generic instead of prebuilding every case.
Just a quick example:

```
$strQuery = 'select 
 models.modelID
,models.manufacturerID
,models.modelName
,manufacturers.manufacturerID
,manufacturers.manufacturerName
,manufacturers.manufacturerDetails
,vehicles.*
from 
models
,manufacturers
,vehicles';

$aWhere = array();
if($min_year != "Select")
{
    array_push($aWhere,'vehicles.year >= ' . $min_year);
}
if($makes != 'All')
{
    array_push($aWhere,'models.manufacturerID=' . $makes);
}

if(count($aWhere) > 0)
{
    $strQuery = $strQuery . ' WHERE ';
}
for($i = 0;$i < count($aWhere);$i++)
{
    if($i == 0)
    {
        $strQuery .= $aWhere[$i];
    }
    else
    {
        $strQuery .= ' AND ' . $aWhere[$i];
    }
}

// Append the other things like order by or limit ...
```

scratch

PS: Do not forget to escape your sql-query variables!

Comment: It doesnot work. There are some mistake, which I have rectified but the query is not getting made up as it was suppose to. I get 

`select models.modelID ,models.manufacturerID ,models.modelName ,manufacturers.manufacturerID ,manufacturers.manufacturerName ,manufacturers.manufacturerDetails ,vehicles.* from models ,manufacturers ,vehicles WHERE AND vehicles.year >= 10models.manufacturerID=3`

Comment: The if condition in the for-loop is wrong. Edited my answer.

Comment: I have not checked your edited answer but your method was correct. I really appreciate this code. I made it work. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really already complex. As far as I understand, you have 9 conditions to display different queries.

I *assume*, this conditions each add a piece of your query.

Right now, you check the conditions and then choose the appropriate query. Why not build your query part by part according to each of the conditions?

Comment: I can do that but the conditions will not get decreased.

Comment: Well, not the conditions. But it looks like that for example if `$makes!="All"` you are adding `models.manufacturerID=$makes AND` after the where. You could CREATE your query only once, but with including 9 times something like `...WHERE "+($makes=="All"?"":"models.manufacturerID=$makes AND ")+"vehicles.manufacturerID=models.manufacturerID...`.